# how to read a line from particular using read command in shell script

Tags: shell

I have the following data in the file `text_file1.txt`

```
subject=/C=US/O=XXX/OU=QA/OU1=12345/OU2=APP/CN=03032015_JKS_2211_Unix_CLB
```

and I want to read the characters based on the requirement.
For example:

1. If I want to read from character 10 to 18 then it should display only `=US/O=XX`

How can i achieve this?
I tried with the following code but it is printing the whole line:

```
n=()
i=0
while read -r -n1 n[i]; do
    echo "Character $i is ${n[i]}"
    ((++i))
done < text_file1.txt
```

Comment: see http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut

Answer (score 1):

Use a better tool for that, like `cut`:

```
cut -c 10-18 text_file1.txt
```

The purpose of `read` is to read from an input and leave the result in a variable.  Like when you need input entered by the user.

Answer (score 0):

As with most things in shell scripting there are many different ways to do this. For example you could do this with [awk](http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/Awk/awk_one_liners.shtml) or [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).

A simpler approach would be to use [substring](http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/Reference/string_operations_in_shell.shtml#Substr) or cut, as other answers have suggested.

Which approach to choose is up to you. Whatever you like best, or whatever fits better with the rest of your script.